# Anyway to decrypt an encrypted sql server stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption

I have a couple of ms sql server (2000) stored procedures encrypted by ex-employee long time ago and things were okay until we need to change it a bit.... is there any way at all to retrieve the source? Or rewrite is the only option?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or for free (Google is your friend):

http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/1,289483,sid87_gci1056869_mem1,00.html

Answer (score 1):

If your time is worth about $99, then this tool may do the job for you.
http://www.elitude.net/sql-decryptor.html

Answer (score 0):

As a rule: In order to decrypt anything you should have the key used during encryption

Comment: I don't think the question is fully understood.  In SQL Server you can encrypt a stored procedure simply by saying WITH ENCRYPTION.  There is no built-in way to decrypt the stored procedure yourself at that point; this is what source control systems are for.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem. My Solution: use tool SQL Compare. You must create one database to compare sql script. Return result script sql is decrypted. Link soft: http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/