# Stored procedure ENCRYPTION option depending on build mode

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, encryption, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I'm working on stored procedures encryption in enterprise project. We have a bunch of SP's that should be protected on production.
 
There is no problem to set `WITH ENCRYPTION` parameter in each SP that is in `sqlproj`. But I want to make this directive optional: if I'm building project in debug mode - do not apply this procedure option, otherwise - use it. Actually main goal here is to get database for developers without encryption, but on production - encrypted SP's. 

Using `PowerShell` script in build task I can modify generated sql file and as a result get script with encryption parameter, but I'm wondering how it would work with `dacpac`.
Any suggestions?

**Update:**

After some time spent playing with `msbuild`. I decided to stop (at least for now) on solution with `PowerShell` script task after `SqlCore` target:

```
<Import Project="$(ExtensionTasksPath)MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks" Condition="Exists('$(ExtensionTasksPath)MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll')" />
  <UsingTask TaskFactory="PowershellTaskFactory" TaskName="CreateDecryptedScript" AssemblyFile="$(PowerShellTaskAssembly)" Condition="Exists('$(PowerShellTaskAssembly)')">
    <ParameterGroup>
      <File Required="true" ParameterType="System.String" />
      <ResultFile Required="true" ParameterType="System.String" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <![CDATA[      
      (Get-Content $file) | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace 'WITH ENCRYPTION', '--WITH ENCRYPTION'} | Set-Content $resultfile    
    ]]>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>
<Target Name="CreateDecryptedScript" AfterTargets="SqlCore">
    <CreateDecryptedScript File="$(OutputPath)$(CreateScriptFileName)" ResultFile="$(OutputPath)$(DecryptedScriptName)" Condition="Exists('$(PowerShellTaskAssembly)')" />
</Target>
```

As a result, after rebuilding project we have script for creating database without encryption.

But `publish` that is invoked from project does not force this stuff to happen and we will alter all SP's with encryption.

Comment: A post deployment script to alter the SP's may do the trick.

Comment: @aclear16 Yes, I was thinking on that but have not found any reasonable solution.

Comment: Adding a project level variable in the place of "WITH ENCRYPTION" might be an option. For your dev environments add this as an empty string or commented line. For environments that should be encrypted, use "WITH ENCRYPTION" for the value. Set those in your publish profiles.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to decrypt "encrypted" stored procedures. I suggest you just don't bother encrypting them.

- [Anyway to decrypt an encrypted sql server stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787629/anyway-to-decrypt-an-encrypted-sql-server-stored-procedure)
- https://duckduckgo.com/?q=decrypt+sql+server+stored+procedure

If you must encrypt them, I suggest a post-deploy step in DEV which decrypts every encrypted stored procedure, one by one. You could create such a step easily using `sp_execsql` and the information at the links.

Comment: Yes, that is the way it could work, but still I'm looking for flexible solution that will not require manipulations on SP's on dev environment.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me. I mean don't encrypt them at all - it is a waste of time.

Comment: Ohh.. I see. But this is not mine decision. And unfortunately I still need encrypt SP's. But thanks for pointing. +1)